# jaxb 1 is not working during JDK 1.4 to JDK 1.7 upgradation of legacy application

Tags: xsd, jaxb, dtd, jdk1.4, jdk1.7

I am migrating an application from jdk 1.4 to jdk 1.7. I faced an issue regarding "marshall()" and "unmarshal()" methods. Project used jaxb-rt-1.0-ea.jar  and I am now compiling the code in jdk 1.7. Could somebody help me out regarding this? 1) Do I need to migrate application from JAXB 1 to JAXB 2? **If yes, please provide steps and tips.** 2) If I can run with jaxb-rt-1.0-ea.jar within jdk 1.7 , then plese suggest steps...

Comment: "please provide steps and tips" - this is way too broad, sorry.

Comment: I understand lexicore ,but atleast give hints if u can

Comment: Tell me if jaxb1-rt-ea.jar works on jdk 1.7 or not?

Comment: JAXB1 should work on Java 7. Not sure what exactly you have in `jaxb-rt-1.0-ea.jar`. Try adding [`jaxb1-impl.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb1-impl) to your project. Which issues do you encounter, exactly?

Comment: I encountered several errors regarding XMLScanner,XMLWriter,MarshallableObject,Dispatcher etc. classes as those classes do not exist in jdk 1.7 now....jaxb1-impl.jar helped to some extent as some errors got resolved...but errors from mentioned classes are there...

Comment: @lexicore, So far what I did is, I converted all .DTD files into .xsd files then using xjc (of JDK 1.7) I have generated the classes. Now I have two doubts:   1) when I am comparing "generated classes  from JDK 1.7" and "generated classes from JDK 1.3 (in existing Application)", I discovered later ones have field variable type as String but same variable of same class (generated from 1.7) is of object type...So, are my generated classes wrong?       2) Do I need to convert old .xsd files to java class too?

Comment: **private String _Environment**  have become **@XmlElement(name = "Environment", required = true)**
    protected Environment environment;